# Flutter: Display content in two columns next to each other

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I need the output as following

[image]

Below is my code

```
Widget _buildShoppingItem() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text("ABCD"),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    placeholder: "https://picsum.photos/100",
                    image: "https://picsum.photos/100",
                    fit: BoxFit.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(child: Text("Grade:")),
                          Container(child: Text("Sashimi")),
                        ],
                      ),

                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(child: Text("Spec:")),
                          Container(child: Text("Skinless Boneless, Full Loins")),
                        ],
                      ),

                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(child: Text("Size:")),
                          Container(child: Text("2-4 kG")),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Spacer(flex: 4,)
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

This gives me the following UI

[image]

As you can see, the code is not giving me the ui OF MY EXPECTATIONS. The UI I get is not properly aligned. The **Grade, Specs** and all are aligned to the bottom, instead to the top. I noticed when the image getting getting bigger, those content further goes down.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: use SizeBox between Text widgets

Comment: @AR: Not clear. whats their `child`? Between text widgets or between text rows?

Comment: Sorry not between Text 
between Rows show my answer for more clearification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `SizeBox` between `Rows`  you can increase this size as per your requirement

```
Widget _buildShoppingItem() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text("ABCD"),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(
                  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    placeholder: "https://picsum.photos/100",
                    image: "https://picsum.photos/100",
                    fit: BoxFit.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(child: Text("Grade:")),
                          Container(child: Text("Sashimi")),
                        ],
                      ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0),

                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(child: Text("Spec:")),
                          Container(child: Text("Skinless Boneless, Full Loins")),
                        ],
                      ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.0),

                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(child: Text("Size:")),
                          Container(child: Text("2-4 kG")),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Spacer(flex: 4,)
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

> Note: Here your Parent widget is Column that's why we are using `SizeBox(height:5)` if we are using Row then we will using like this `SizeBox(width:5)`

Answer (score 0):

If the top instead of the bottom, how about this?

```
Widget _buildShoppingItem() {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // add this line
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Text("ABCD"),
          )
        ],
        ...
```

[image: align top sample]